# Passing command line arguments to script running on Tessel

Tags: javascript, node.js, johnny-five, tessel

I am trying to run a simple script for Tessel passing command arguments and expect them to be available in `process.argv`, but only getting the first two of them.

Running script via `t2 run index.js myparam`
Logging process.argv I am getting `[ '/usr/bin/node', '/tmp/remote-script/index.js' ]`, but not getting `myparam` as third parameter.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I am trying to do the same thing and it is not working.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to find any solution. If you do, please let me know.

Comment: @ryder If you are using webpack, you can use this to parse them: https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader

Answer (score 0):

Try `t2 run index.js [ myparam ]`.

Source: https://github.com/tessel/t2-cli/blob/558a132adfbecf18e569b1c16991c0605a953a6b/bin/tessel-2.js#L572-L593.

Comment: I guess you are passing params to t2 this way, but you cannot get them in your JS code.